# Square Spiral Co-ordinate

Tags: java, c++, logic, spiral

I want to find if a point (x,y)where x,y integers satisfy the spiral square.
(0,0) (0,1) (1,1) (1,2) (0,2) (-1,2) (-2,2) (-2,1) (-2,0) ans so on.....

[image]

How do I do it?
I want the logic for a java or c++ function.

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145584/given-coordinates-find-the-number-at-that-coordinates-in-spiral-matrix#comment39146760_25145584.

Comment: What have you tried? Generally, SO is not a good place to just give problem description and ask for code. That almost always gets you a ton of downvotes... But one way to get started for a brute-force solution is, write program which produces the points (or line segments) of the spiral, and then see where that takes you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode logic:

```
Start with x=0, y=0, dist=0, direction=1
Loop
  x += (++dist * direction)
  WritePoint(x,y)
  y += (++dist * direction)
  WritePoint(x,y)
  direction *= -1
LoopEnd
```

Take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do this operation:

`(operator)(operation)(amount)`

where operator alternates as x,y,x,y,...(use % operator for that), operation alternates as +,+,-,-,+,+,-,-,+,+...(again use % operator for that) and amount changes as 1,2,3,...

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. To solve it I found the indexes where you need to change the direction (up to ~i=36) by drawing it then found the formula like you would on a pattern recognition IQ test.

```
  const size = 100;
  let x = 500;  // 500 is center x
  let y = 500;  // 500 is center y
  let d = 'right';
  let n = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // change the direction
    if (i === Math.pow(n, 2) - n) {
      d = 'right';
    } else if (i === Math.pow(n, 2)) {
      d = 'down';
    } else if (i === Math.pow(n, 2) + n) {
      d = 'left';
    } else if (i === Math.pow(n, 2) + (n * 2 + 1)) {
      d = 'up';
      n += 2;
    }

    // get the current x and y.
    if (d === 'right') {
      x += size;
    } else if (d === 'left') {
      x -= size;
    } else if (d === 'down') {
      y += size;
    } else {
      y -= size;
    }
  }
```