# Formula for returning X or Y on a grid spiral, but only the direction changes?

Tags: math, grid, coordinates, spiral

I am trying to find two formulae that will return either X or Y from an n input. These coordinates should be on a spiral grid pattern, similar to an Ulam spiral, but n signifies not the position on the spiral, but only the direction changes.

```
n = 1, return 0,1;
n = 2, return 1,1;
n = 3, return 1,-1;
n = 4, return -1,-1;
n = 5, return -1,2;
n = 6, return 2,2;
n = 7, return 2,-2;
n = 8, return -2,-2;
```

Should be two discrete formulae single, just supply n and get X and another to get Y. Effectively [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228464/square-spiral-co-ordinate) just in single lines for X or Y with n as loop position input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the X values:

```
0 1 1 -1 -1 2 2 -2 -2 3 3 -3 -3 ...
```

Perform the obvious grouping and compare with n:

```
n: 1   2  3  4  5   6  7  8  9   10 ...
x: 0   1  1 -1 -1   2  2 -2 -2    3 ...
```

Add another row for k = (n+2)/4 (rounding down, I don't know how to indicate the `floor` function in ascii) and m = n mod 4:

```
k: 0   1  1  1  1   2  2  2  2    3 ...
m: 1   2  3  0  1   2  3  0  1    2
```

That should be enough to show how to render x in whichever language you like best.

And then y is easy: y(n) = x(n+1)

Comment: I actually just need a formula, not using a specific language.

Comment: @user2280032: Isn't it obvious? x=k(2*(m/2)-1), where m/2 is rounded down.

Comment: It probably would be if math class didn't consist of just learning things by heart. Anyhow, I have X correctly now using: x=floor((n+2)/4)*(2*floor((n%4)/2)-1)

When I now do y=x*(n-1) however I get values increasing by power 3, I am back to trial an error on that, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Could you simply provide:
X=
Y=
for given n?

Comment: @user2280032: As you say, learning things by heart will never give you mathematical ability. And you must develop some mathematical ability, or the answer will be of no use to you. When I say `y(n)=x(n+1)`, I mean that once you know what x is when n=11, that's what y is when n=10. So if you want to know y when n=100, look at x when n=101. If you want a simple formula for y, work it out.

Comment: That part I did misunderstand, sorry about that. I managed to put 2 and 2 together and get the correct formula out of this now, thank you.

x = floor((n+2)/4)*(2*floor((n%4)/2)-1);
y = floor(((n)+3)/4)*(2*floor(((n+1)%4)/2)-1);